# What is the name of the typography symbol for the line under which totals/solutions are written?

Tags: notation, terminology, arithmetic

I've tried googling for this, but no keywords I can come up with provide meaningful results.

Specifically, the line used in basic arithmetic for addition, subtraction, and multiplication.

Does this symbol have a formal name? Does this symbol have a proper unicode or mathml representation?

Comment: A vinculum is a line that goes *over* other symbols. Not sure what's the name of the line that goes under. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vinculum_(symbol)

Comment: In German we call it "Strich" (engl.: stroke), e.g., "unter dem Strich haben alle diese Massnahmen nichts gebracht" – meaning that the result of all these measures is $\leq0$.

Comment: For what it's worth, in TeX it's an hline: $$\begin{tabular}{c@{\,}c@{\,}c@{\,}c}
  & 1 & 2 & 3 \\
+ &   & 3 & 4 \\
\hline
  & 1 & 5 & 7 \\
\end{tabular}$$

Comment: Not what you're seeking, but perhaps worthy of mention is the "bottom line," as is used in accounting.